# Plot output of FourierTransform in mathematica

Tags: plotting, fourier-analysis

I'm a too newbie in mathematica.I've gotton my output correctly as Shown below:

```
FourierTransform[(20 ( Cos[2 20* \[Pi] * x] Sin[3* \[Pi] * x])/(\[Pi] *x)), x, f, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]
```

[image]

But unfortunately when I want to plot the output I've received a wrong answer.

```
x[k_] := FourierTransform[(20 ( Cos[2 20* \[Pi] * x] Sin[3* \[Pi] *x])/(\[Pi] *x)), x, f, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]  

Plot[x[k], {f, -100, 100}]
```

[image]
what is my mistake?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A couple of problems... you've defined `x` as a function of `k` but there is no `k` in the definition. Also, the changes in the function occur outside the region you are plotting (which is more obvious from the simplified form).

Thus, take the Fourier transform and simplify:

```
FourierTransform[(20 (Cos[2 20*π*x] Sin[3*π*x])/(π*x)), x,
   f, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}] // FullSimplify
```

Set a function equal to the output

```
x[f_] := 5 (Sign[f - 37 π] - Sign[f + 37 π] + 
            Sign[-f + 43 π] + Sign[f + 43 π])
```

and plot

```
Plot[x[f], {f, -200, 200}]
```

[image]